# How can I use 'sed' in a Linux Bash script file to comment out a particular line with tabbed spacing?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

I wish to add '#' to the beginning of this line within a particular file using sed.  The script will be run within a .sh file, not typed into the console.

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

Should be:

```
#auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

I'm currently trying commands similar to:

```
sudo sed -e '/auth[[:tab:]][success=1[[:space:]]default=ignore][[:tab:]]pam_unix.so[[:space:]]nullok_secure/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

I know the above command is wrong, as `[[:tab:]]` is not a valid command. I just want to show where the tabs occur.

Any help is appreciated!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works...

```
sed -e '/^auth\t\[success=1\ default=ignore\]\tpam_unix.so\ nullok_secure/ s/^/#/' -i file
```

I'm just using `\t` instead of `[[:tab:]]`

And `\` instead of `[[:space:]]`

Comment: "Linux" is very broad so this might work on some Linuxes and fail on others.  Which `sed` version is this?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu you can use `\t` for tab, and I believe that's even specified in POSIX.

```
/auth\t\[success=1 default=ignore\]\tpam_unix.so nullok_secure/
```

I think I've run into issues doing that on BSD though, but if you don't really care that it's exactly a tab, and would accept the line even if it has other types of spaces you could be a little more flexible

```
/auth[[:space:]]\+\[success=1 default=ignore\]pam_unix.so[[:space:]]nullok_secure/
```

which is a GNU-ism for the `\+` to mean one or more of the previous, to be more POSIX-y you could do it

```
/auth[[:space:]][[:space:]]*\[success=1 default=ignore\]pam_unix.so[[:space:]]nullok_secure/
```

(And note that the `[:space:]` character class does not contain only the space character, it's the set of white space characters, which includes tabs.)

Also note, we have to escape the `[` in the pattern you're matching, or it will define a character class of things to match, which is certainly not what you're trying for here.

As another option, assuming your `common-auth` looks like mine, that's the only line that has `success=1` on it so you could just use that, although it's more fragile if other people make changes to the file some time.

Comment: This works too! Thanks so much! 

I had been trying ```\t``` before, but I was getting a couple of other things wrong.

Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You're making this very hard on yourself.  The authconfig files are standard and won't need all of the regex you're using.

```
sed -i 's/^auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure/#auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure/' /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

If you really want to be specific though, I wouldn't use the space and tab lookups.  Just look for the text you want and the white space in between.

Comment: As per comments in another answer, the `[` character is a regex metacharacter, and would need to be escaped.  Perhaps you should also describe how to use literal tabs (easy if you write a script in an editor, requires ctrl-V secret sauce in many interactive shells).

Comment: Also, repeating the substitution text verbatim is kinda fugly.  The OP's script is better in this regard; or you could simply use `&` in the substitution to refer back to the entire matched text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Couldn't get this to work though :/  The regex in my above expression is leftover from a previous command I was using and left just in case. Thanks again for helping me out!